# Gravar dados no banco

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Olá, tenho uma função em javascript que adiciona campos em meu formulário. E quero gravar os valores desses campos em meu banco de dados.
O código dos campos são esses.

```
            <div><input type="radio" name="opcao2" value="Mae"/><label>Mae</label>
            <input type="radio" name="opcao2" value="Pai"/><label>Pai</label>
            <input type="radio" name="opcao2" value="Madrasta"/><label>Madrastra</label>
            <input type="radio" name="opcao2" value="Padrastro"/><label>Padrastro</label>
            <input type="radio" name="opcao2" value="Avó"/><label>Avó</label>
            <input type="radio" name="opcao2" value="Avô"/><label>Avô</label>
            <input type="radio" name="opcao2" value=""/><label>Outro</label>
            <input type="text" name="opcao2" />
            </br>
            <label>Nome:</label>
            <input type='text' name='nome_resp'/>
            <label>RG:</label>
            <input type="text" name="rg_resp"/> 
            <label>CPF:</label>
            <input type="text" name="cpf_resp"/> 
            <label>Telefone:</label>
            <input type="text" name="telefone_resp"/>
            <label>Celular:</label>
            <input type="text" name="celular_resp"/>
            <label>E-mail</label>
            <input type="text" name="email_resp"/></div>
```

Meu PHP ficou assim:

```
$respon = new Responsavel($db);

$respon->id_aluno = $_POST['rg'];//gravar com RG
$respon->parente1 = $_POST['opcao2'];
$respon->nome1 = $_POST['nome_resp'];
$respon->rg1 = $_POST['rg_resp'];
$respon->cpf1 = $_POST['cpf_resp'];
$respon->telefone1 = $_POST['telefone_resp'];
$respon->celular1 = $_POST['celular_resp'];
$respon->email1 = $_POST['email_resp']; 
if($respon->criar()){
    echo "<script>alert ('Gravado com sucesso')</script>";
}
```

Comment: Qual problema você está enfrentando? Mensagem de Erro? O que não está dando certo?

Comment: Aparentemente não há  nenhum erro, se houver está na classe, que não foi postada.

Comment: Assim na hora que vou preencher o cadastro eu escolho quantos campos eu quero adicionar. Só que se eu declaro todas as variáveis  na parte do php ele aparece um erro pois eu posso ou não adicionar esse campos a mais.

Comment: O problema é o `criar()`.

Comment: Assim se eu deixar só esses campos com esse php ok ele funciona. o problema e quando eu adiciono mais campos.

Comment: voce esta passando os dados via get ou post?

Comment: Coloque a classe `Responsavel` aqui também, com certeza o erro está nela. E de onde vem o `rg` ? Sendo que no formulário não tem input com tal nome

Comment: Estou passando os dados via POST.
Então, a parte do formulário onde tem o rg existe só não postei. E a classe está correta também só preciso saber como eu gravo vários dados quando eu adiciono mais campos. OBS: acabei não mostrando, mas logo abaixo do meu último input ali tem um botão que adiciona(ou clono) esses campos anteriores.

Comment: @ArthurBalmanto No javascript, tente gerar um json dos campos adicionas, e fazer o submit dos dados do form utilizando  AJAX. No php, utilize a função json_decode() para manipular estas informações.

Comment: @AndréRamos ok, obrigado vou tentar aqui.